# How to conform to a protocol based on OS version ?

Tags: ios, swift

In an app targeting iOS 8.0 and above, I want to use an SFSafariViewController on iOS 9.0 and above and a fallback WebView controller on older devices.

I need those View controllers to conform to a protocol `protocol SomeWebViewProtocol`

I can do it directly for the fallback WebView controller (`extension FallBackViewController: SomeWebViewProtocol { ... }`), but how do I do it for the SFSafariViewController ? `if #available(iOS 9, *) { ... }` is not an option since extensions must be at file level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example should suffice:

```
struct Foo
{

}

@available(iOS 9, *)
protocol Bar
{

}

@available(iOS 9, *)
extension Foo: Bar
{

}
```

Simply add `@available(iOS <version>, *)` to the top of your declaration.